# Validate email and return JSON in Lumen Controller

Tags: php, ajax, lumen

I'm trying to validate an email address with PHP `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` in a small app built using Lumen.

I send an AJAX GET request when the form is submitted that should then validate using the code inside newsletterController.php, If I hardcode an email address in `valid_email('email@email.com')` then the validation works, I am not able to pass the email address from the form with the variable `$email`.

How can i get `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` working correctly and return with the appropriate response?

NewsletterController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NewsletterController extends Controller
{
    public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');


        function valid_email($email) {

            return !!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);


        }

        if( valid_email($email) ) {

            return response()->json(["valid"]);



        } else {

            return response()->json(["invalid"]);

        }

    }

}
```

routes.php

```
$app->get('newsletter/subscribe', 'NewsletterController@subscribe');
```

AJAX Call via jQuery

```
$(".submit-email").click(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get("newsletter/subscribe", function(data, status){
        console.log("data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    })
    .done(function() {
        //console.log( "done" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        //console.log( "finished" );
    });            
});
```

Form

```
<form class="join-newsletter">
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" class="email-address">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="submit-email button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that you didn't send the email input to that controller.

Solution 1:

`$.get // should send the email via query string.
$request->input('email'); -> change to $request->query('email');`

Solution 2:

`$.get -> $.post, set the request input email for it also
Change the route method to post`

Another point, you can test without ajax first (by form submit) and apply jquery after done the basic process.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it could be because I am not passing the email input correctly. I am new to Lumen and PHP in general. I updated my question with an edit to `newsletterController.php`, If i hardcode an email address as a parameter of `valid_email()` it works as expected and I get either 'valid' or 'invalid' so i think this confirms I am not passing email value properly. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you try the solution 1? Change "newsletter/subscribe" to "newsletter/subscribe?email=" + $('input[type=email]').val() on the JS code, and following the change for Lumen controller method as I mentioned above.

Comment: Now I added the `"newsletter/subscribe?email=" + $('input[type=email]').val()` to the AJAX I get the 'email is valid' response back, thank you! I have a lot of reading to do now in the Lumen docs...